# Valid query gives output but can't export to CSV

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems with export the outcome of a query to CSV. I'm having a query which is outputting things to my screen in PHPMyAdmin, but when I want to export the outcome I get this errormessage:

```html
<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
    <div class="error"><h1>Fout</h1>
<p><strong>SQL-query:</strong>
<a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.6%2Fen%2Fselect.html" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentatie" alt="Documentatie" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a><a href="tbl_sql.php?sql_query=SELECT+p.productid%2C+group_concat%28concat%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F%27%2Cpa.bestandsnaam%29%29+as+afbeelding_volledig%2C+GROUP_CONCAT%28pc.productcategorie%29+AS+categorie+FROM+%60product%60+WHERE+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+1+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112631klauterhelling.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112708klauterhelling2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112745klauterhelling4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112708klauterhelling2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112745klauterhelling4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112726klauterhelling3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112631klauterhelling.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112708klauterhelling2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112745klauterhelling4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112726klauterhelling3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112726klauterhelling3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducte%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Grote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+11+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125641springkussensmarkt.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125622springkussenklein2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125703springkussenklein.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125641springkussensmarkt.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125703springkussenklein.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125622springkussenklein2.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Kleine+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+13+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125540springkussenkasteel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125540springkussenkasteel.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Kleine+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+14+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130142springkussenkrokodil.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130120img-20130501-wa0001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130029img-20130501-wa0003.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130142springkussenkrokodil.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130120img-20130501-wa0001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130029img-20130501-wa0003.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130142springkussenkrokodil.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130120img-20130501-wa0001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804130029img-20130501-wa0003.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CMultiplay+springkussens%2CMultiplay+springkussens%2CMultiplay+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+16+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120148springkussenclownclub.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120137springkussenclownclub2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120124springkussenclownclub3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120124springkussenclownclub3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120112springkussenclownclub4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120148springkussenclownclub.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120148springkussenclownclub.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120137springkussenclownclub2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120124springkussenclownclub3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120112springkussenclownclub4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F201308031201%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Overdekte+springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+17+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121143springkussengroot001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121112springkussensmarkt.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604194130p5249891.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120950springkussengroot002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121143springkussengroot001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121112springkussensmarkt.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604194130p5249891.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803120950springkussengroot002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121143springkussengroot001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803121112springkussensmarkt.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604194130p5249891.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2F%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Overdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+18+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115007springkussencircus1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202329img-20120923-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115058springkussencircus3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115043springkussencircus2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115007springkussencircus1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202329img-20120923-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115058springkussencircus3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115043springkussencircus2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115007springkussencircus1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202329img-20120923-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803115058springkussencircus3.jpg%2Ch%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+21+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202446img-20121210-wa0006.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202426img-20121210-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803112718ministormbaan.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202446img-20121210-wa0006.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202426img-20121210-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202426img-20121210-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803112718ministormbaan.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202446img-20121210-wa0006.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803112718ministormbaan.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202446img-20121210-wa0006.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812202426img-20121210-wa0005.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.faesente%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Stormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CKleine+springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+24+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125507ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125507ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125507ballenbak.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+25+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727123523superstormbaan002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727123523superstormbaan002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803105741stormbaan+fc+oss.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2014060419393310411346_744207755630128_821504273218410387_n.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803105741stormbaan+fc+oss.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727123420stormbaan.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727123420stormbaan.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727123523superstormbaan002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2014060419393310411346_744207755630128_821504273218410387_n.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803105741stormbaan+fc+oss.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2014060419393310411346%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Grote+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+26+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124358superstormbaan001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124358superstormbaan001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130831151735img-20130824-wa0000.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124549superstormbaan002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124518superstormbaan003.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124518superstormbaan003.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124358superstormbaan001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124358superstormbaan001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130831151735img-20130824-wa0000.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727124549superstormbaan002.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130831151735img-20130824-wa0000.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.faesen%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Zeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CStormbanen+%26+zeephellingen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+27+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111452buikschuifbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111452buikschuifbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604193509p5249896.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111542buikschuifbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111542buikschuifbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111607965850_548487438522915_1297475313_o.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111607965850_548487438522915_1297475313_o.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111452buikschuifbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604193509p5249896.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20140604193509p5249896.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713111542buikschuifbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.faesentertainme%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Grote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpri
gkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CWaterattracties%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CWaterattracties%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CWaterattracties%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+springkussens%2CWaterattracties%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+28+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113331gladiatorenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113331gladiatorenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113331gladiatorenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113331gladiatorenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113331gladiatorenspel.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Grote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CInflatables%2CGrote+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+29+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812190610img-20120324-wa0001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803113719sumoworstelen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812191402imag0108.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812190636img-20120324-wa0000.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130803113719sumoworstelen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812191402imag0108.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812190610img-20120324-wa0001.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130812190636img-20120324-wa0000.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Zeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+30+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125355skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150708084045img_0928.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150708084045img_0928.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125328skelterbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125328skelterbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125315skelterbaan1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125355skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125355skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150708084045img_0928.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150708084045img_0928.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125328skelterbaan2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125315skelterbaan1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fw%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Grote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CSkelterbanen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CSkelterbanen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CSkelterbanen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CSkelterbanen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+31+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130808184929kazenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115353kruiptunnel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130808184929kazenspel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115353kruiptunnel.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Zeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+32+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112203bungeerun3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112124bungeerun1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112146bungeerun2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112203bungeerun3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112203bungeerun3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112124bungeerun1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112124bungeerun1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112146bungeerun2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112203bungeerun3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112124bungeerun1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112146bungeerun2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713112146bungeerun2.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%2CSpringkussens%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+springkussens%2CZeskamp%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+33+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2017110514200135dd3c1e-fc69-41fd-af6c-499b0032baff.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211302rodeostier1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211232rodeostier2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2017110514200135dd3c1e-fc69-41fd-af6c-499b0032baff.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211302rodeostier1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211232rodeostier2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F2017110514200135dd3c1e-fc69-41fd-af6c-499b0032baff.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211302rodeostier1.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20150304211232rodeostier2.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Zeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CGrote+zeskamp+spelen%2CWestern%2CWestern%2CWestern%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+34+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727170202Ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727165842ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727170202Ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727165842ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727170202Ballenbak.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727165842ballenbak.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Overdekte+springkussens%2COverdekte+springkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CSpringkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%2CKleine+springkussens%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+35+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113830skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113741bigwheel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113755bigwheels2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113809bigwheels3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113809bigwheels3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113830skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113741bigwheel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113741bigwheel.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113755bigwheels2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113809bigwheels3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113830skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130713113830skelterbaan4.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.fae%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Funbikes%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CZeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKermis+attracties%2CZeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKermis+attracties%2CFunbikes%2CZeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CFunbikes%2CZeskamp%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKermis+attracties%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+36+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115220skelterbaan3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115132crossbike.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115220skelterbaan3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115132crossbike.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115220skelterbaan3.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130727115132crossbike.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Funbikes%2CFunbikes%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CKleine+zeskamp+spelen%2CZeskamp%2CZeskamp%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+37+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125218minifietsjes.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125218minifietsjes.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130914113502pietenfietsen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130914113502pietenfietsen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125218minifietsjes.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125218minifietsjes.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130914113502pietenfietsen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130914113502pietenfietsen.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125218minifietsjes.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130914113502pietenfietsen.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Behendigheid+spellen%2CKleine+spellen%2CBehendigheid+spellen%2CKleine+spellen%2CCircus%2COud+Hollandse+spelen%2CCircus%2COud+Hollandse+spelen%2CFunbikes%2CFunbikes%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+38+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125247steps.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Funbikes%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+39+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125152step.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Funbikes%27%29+OR+%28%60product%60.%60productid%60+%3D+40+AND+.%60afbeelding_volledig%60+%3D+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fimages%2Fproducten%2Fgroot%2F20130804125423skelters.jpg%27+AND+.%60categorie%60+%3D+%27Funbikes%27%29+GROUP+BY+p.productid+&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=faesentert_site&amp;table=product&amp;token=28abec1be67dfe7169ad5c8f3f2bd4b3"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Wijzigen" alt="Wijzigen" class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Wijzigen</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<code class="sql"><pre>
SELECT p.productid
</pre></code>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL meldt: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.6%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-server.html" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentatie" alt="Documentatie" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
</p>
<code>
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'http://www.url.com/images/producten/groot/20130713112631klauterh' at line 1
</code><br />
</div>
```

For me it's hard to get clear whats going wrong here.... It seems to cut off something, but I don't understand why. Somebody have an idea???

Query:
SELECT p.productid, group_concat(concat('http://www.faesentertainment.nl/images/producten/groot/',pa.bestandsnaam)) as afbeelding_volledig, GROUP_CONCAT(pc.productcategorie) AS categorie FROM product AS p INNER JOIN productproductcategorie AS ppc ON ppc.productid = p.productid INNER JOIN productcategorie AS pc on ppc.productcategorieid = pc.productcategorieid inner join productafbeeldingen AS pa on p.productid = pa.productid
where productid <> 0
GROUP BY p.productid

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with a workaround which I really can't understand why it works.

Original query:

```
SELECT p.productid, group_concat(concat('http://www.faesentertainment.nl/images/producten/groot/',pa.bestandsnaam)) as afbeelding_volledig, 
GROUP_CONCAT(pc.productcategorie) AS categorie
FROM product AS p 
INNER JOIN productproductcategorie AS ppc ON ppc.productid = p.productid
INNER JOIN productcategorie AS pc on ppc.productcategorieid = pc.productcategorieid
inner join productafbeeldingen AS pa on p.productid = pa.productid
where productid <> 0 
GROUP BY p.productid
```

This one works in frontend but not in export to CSV.

When I change it to:

```
SELECT pa.productid, group_concat(concat('http://www.faesentertainment.nl/images/producten/groot/',pa.bestandsnaam)) as afbeelding_volledig, 
GROUP_CONCAT(pc.productcategorie) AS categorie
FROM product AS p 
INNER JOIN productproductcategorie AS ppc ON ppc.productid = p.productid
INNER JOIN productcategorie AS pc on ppc.productcategorieid = pc.productcategorieid
inner join productafbeeldingen AS pa on p.productid = pa.productid
where productid <> 0 
GROUP BY pa.productid
```

Everything is fine. I really can't understand this....